# jquery ui Progress bar do not stop when clicking on stop button

Tags: html, jquery-ui, progress-bar

I am trying to use jquery ui progressbar. Below is code i have

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#progressBar').progressbar({
             value: 1
         });
});
var statusTracker ;
var percentage = 0;
function checkStatus() {//function to fill progress bar
 percentage = percentage +5;
 $("#progressBar > .ui-progressbar-value").animate({
  width : percentage + "%"
 });
 statusTracker = setTimeout(function() {//call this function every 20ms
  checkStatus()
 }, 20);
}

function startProgress(){
checkStatus();
}

function stop(){//stop progress bar


clearTimeout(statusTracker);

}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="progressBar" style="opcity:1; height:30px;width:500px;" ></div>
<p>
<input type="submit" value="Start" onclick="startProgress()"/>

<input type="submit" value="Stop" onclick="stop()"/>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

When i am clicking on stop button progress bar do not stop.
My clearTimeout() function is not working. 
Any help will be appreciable .

Comment: @Cory I want to stop this progress bar by clicking on stop() function.

Comment: Below is the link of demo of my above question
http://jsfiddle.net/kumarohit21/A7Yhs/

ON clicking stop button , progress bar must be stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your timeout period is way too small. The second parameter to `setTimeout()` is the number of *milliseconds* until execution. The browser has already put all (100 / 5) 20 steps of the animation on the stack long before it receives your "stop" instruction.

Try setting the timeout interval to something like 500 (1/2 second) and try it again. Also, I think you'd be better off with `setInterval()` in this situation, instead of using an infinite `setTimeout()` loop. Something like this:

```
var statusTracker;
var percentage = 0;

function checkStatus() {
    percentage = percentage + 5;
    $("#progressBar > .ui-progressbar-value").animate({
        width : percentage + "%"
    });
    if (percentage == 100) stop();
}

function startProgress() {
    statusTracker = setInterval(checkStatus, 500);
}

function stop() {
    clearInterval(statusTracker);
}

$(function() {
    $('#progressBar').progressbar({
        value: 1
    });
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/A7Yhs/9/)**